# How do I rebuild an array of objects in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, typescript

I have a array of objects that contain array of objects. I would like to know how I can browse it. I tried with a map but the parent data doesn't come up...

My result:

```
 let cars = [{   name: 'Volvo',   equipments:
         [{
           name: 'saddleries',
           options:[array],
         }]
       }];
```

I would like this result :

```
 let cars = [{   name: 'Volvo (1) equipment',   equipments:
     [{
       name: 'saddleries (2) options',
       options:
         [{name: 'leather'},
           {name: 'fabrics'},
     }], }]
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried with a map but the parent data doesn't come up". Share the map code you've tried.

Comment: By 'browse it', you mean you want to traverse it and get values?

Comment: Yes because I have   [array] [array] :(

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to create a new array where the name contains the length of `equipments` or `options`. Try this:

```js
const cars = [
  {
    name: "Volvo",
    equipments: [
      {
        name: "saddleries",
        options: [{ name: "leather" }, { name: "fabrics" }],
      },
    ],
  },
];

const newCars = cars.map(({ name, equipments }) => ({
  name: `${name} (${equipments.length}) equipment`,
  equipments: equipments.map(({ name, options }) => ({
    name: `${name} (${options.length}) options`,
    options,
  })),
}));

console.log(newCars);
```

I'm using [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) here to pick out the `name` and `equipment` properties from the cars, and `name` and `options` form the equipment objects. The `` strings are [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), if you're not familiar with them.

Comment: Thank you ! And How I can to display all without [array] [array] in options ?

Comment: @coco Well how are you "displaying" it? What do you mean by "display"?

Comment: When I put a console.log

Comment: Click on the "array" in the console? Expand the tree from the arrows on the left?